# Does the Ethereum Foundation foundation accept proposals?

Tags: dapp-development, foundation

Can you expand on the role of the foundation in supporting new projects? What is the proposal time-frame and format if there is one? How does one interact with the foundation? Etc...

Answer (score 2):

There is https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs
This is similar to Bitcoins Improvement Proposal track and [EIP-1](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1.mediawiki) explains the procedure.

Also, you can apply for grants that improve Ethereum. Normally you would need to have already started with a project to do so before applying.

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/04/07/devgrants-help/

http://www.blockchainlabs.org/blockgrant-x-en/